# How to perform specific object recognition on a image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-recognition

I have  3 images of differents objets : a smartphone, a shirt and a packet of pasta.
I want to perform recognition of each object on any images containing one of these objects.
For example, if we have the same phone in a picture, i want to be able to see the phone with a bounded box drawn in this picture. If the phone is different, nothing should be drawn.

I first tried to perform object recognition using neural network like Mask R-CNN with python and tensorflow. But i realized that i haven't a huge training dataset, only my 3 images. Neural network algorithms seem to be adapted to recognize concept like dog,  smartphone, landscape but not a particular dog, a specific smartphone or a specific landscape.

To get to the point, if i have in input any picture that contain the same smartphone, the same shirt or the same packet of pasta, i want the program to detect that.

What algorithms are best suited to perform this recognition ?

Comment: This seems quite broad, and likely off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Why not use a pretrained model like VGG19?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [COCO](http://cocodataset.org/#home) dataset. Since the COCO weights have already been trained on thousands of items and images, you should just be able to run the `splash` feature to help detection with Mask RCNN.

[image]

Worst case scenario, if you want to train your own dataset, just find a lot of photos online relating to the objects you want to detect, annotate them, then train.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Aaron Jones . But as i said in the question, i want to detect specific objects instances. I don't want to recognize generic objects like persons, airplanes, bottles for example, but recognize Aaron(a specific person), a Boeing 787(a specific airplane), a coke bottle(a specific type of bottle). Train a dataset over thousand of pictures is adapted to recognize generic objets i think.

Comment: @samourayonly You will most likely have to collect a bunch of images of the spacific object that you want, then train a model based on that, since you want the dataset to be very specific, and you have a limited beginning images.